# Inconsistency between Horizons Cartesian Vector and Elements Ephemerides

Tags: horizons

I am puzzled why the 'Argument of Perifocus' in the 'Elements' ephemeris of JPL Horizons data seems to change at almost twice the rate compared to that derived from the 'Cartesian Vector' data (by looking up the point in time where the radial velocity changes the sign and getting the angle by arctan(y/x) for the corresponding coordinates x,y). For Mercury, the result from the latter method is consistent with the published value for its precession, but for the Elements ephemeris it is almost a factor 2 too high. Am I missing something as far as the definition of the 'Argument of Perifocus' is concerned?
Below the figures from the Horizons output for the two cases:

```
Target body name: Mercury (199)                   {source: DE431mx}
Center body name: Sun (10)                        {source: DE431mx}
Center-site name: BODY CENTER
Output units    : AU-D                                                         
**Output type     : GEOMETRIC cartesian states**
Output format   : 3 (position, velocity, LT, range, range-rate)
Reference frame : ICRF/J2000.0                                                 
Coordinate systm: Ecliptic and Mean Equinox of Reference Epoch  


 260449.687500000 = **B.C. 4000-Jan-27 04:30:00.0000** TDB 
 **X = 1.164743462150131E-01 Y = 2.850041983620870E-01** Z = 8.389268356192319E-03
 VX=-3.128451713699121E-02 VY= 1.265881361215312E-02 VZ= 4.254899234299577E-03
 LT= 1.778860079563158E-03 RG= 3.080000750548330E-01 RR=-1.081697566119120E-06

**w1=arctan(y/x)=67.771 deg**


3182087.729166667 = **A.D. 4000-Feb-28 05:30:00.0000** TDB 
 **X = 5.116306925306278E-02 Y = 3.023233324889192E-01** Z = 2.103345767836515E-02
 VX=-3.347343877524768E-02 VY= 5.427345568155732E-03 VZ= 3.354722757033892E-03
 LT= 1.775062722517847E-03 RG= 3.073425830640897E-01 RR=-3.999603040263569E-06

**w2=arctan(y/x)=80.395 deg**

**w2-w1 = 12.62 deg/8000.08 years = 568 arcsec/100 year**s (published value 574 arcsec/100 years)


**================================================**

Target body name: Mercury (199)                   {source: DE431mx}
Center body name: Sun (10)                        {source: DE431mx}
Center-site name: BODY CENTER
Output units    : AU-D, deg, Julian Day Number (Tp)                            
**Output type     : GEOMETRIC osculating elements**
Reference frame : ICRF/J2000.0                                                 
Coordinate systm: Ecliptic and Mean Equinox of Reference Epoch 


 260449.687500000 = **B.C. 4000-Jan-27 04:30:00.0000** TDB 
 EC= 2.043363097473196E-01 QR= 3.080000741369763E-01 IN= 7.355089152666030E+00
 OM= 5.558492230906509E+01 **W = 1.229521123474350E+01** Tp=   260449.689197067026
 N = 4.092344516439835E+00 MA= 3.599930550170328E+02 **TA= 3.599892613233741E+02**
 A = 3.870983154191240E-01 AD= 4.661965567012716E-01 PR= 8.796913323250327E+01

 **w1= 12.295 deg**

 3182087.729166667 = **A.D. 4000-Feb-28 05:30:00.0000** TDB 
 EC= 2.060348142966012E-01 QR= 3.073425706719665E-01 IN= 6.886602138452942E+00
 OM= 4.578578064707545E+01 **W = 3.484244211886764E+01** Tp=  3182087.735363342799
 N = 4.092344820332250E+00 MA= 3.599746410639116E+02 **TA= 3.599606351364515E+02**
 A = 3.870982962554988E-01 AD= 4.668540218390312E-01 PR= 8.796912670002531E+01

 **w2= 34.842 deg**

 **w2-w1= 22.55 deg/8000.08 years = 1015 arcsec/100 years** (published value 574 arcsec/100 years)
```

================================================

This result is essentially the same if a different period is chosen

Comment: Can you show an example of your numbers, rather than make every reader repeat this exercise just to see if this is true or not? Thanks!

Comment: I added the numbers above as requested

Comment: That looks great. Thank you, and *Welcome to Space!*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You made three mistakes here, two major and one rather minor. These are

- Using $\arctan(y/x)$ in the Cartesian calculation.
- Using $\omega_2 - \omega_1$ in the orbital elements calculation.
- (Minor) Using 8000.08 years in both calculations as the span of time.

I'll address the last issue first. Astronomers use Julian years and Julian centuries. A Julian year is exactly 365.25 astronomical days long, where an astronomical day is exactly 86400 SI seconds long. There is no need to bother with leap years or leap seconds with this scheme. You should have used 7999.009012 years (or 79.99009012 centuries) instead of 8000.08 years.

The first two issues are related. Using $\arctan(y/x)$ as you did in the first calculation is not how the precession of Mercury is defined, nor is the change in the argument of perihelion, which is what you used in the second calculation.

Note that in the case of orbital elements that the right ascension of ascending node decreased from 55.58492230906509° to 45.78578064707545° over that 79.99 century span of time, or a nodal precession of -9.79914°. One needs to account for this nodal precession to obtain a full picture of Mercury's perihelion precession.

The standard approach is to use at the change in Mercury's longitude of perihelion, the sum of the right ascension of ascending node and the argument of perihelion. With this, $\Delta \bar\omega = (45.78578°+34.84244°)-(55.58492°+12.29521°)=12.74809°$. Dividing this by 79.99009012 centuries yields 0.159371°/century, or 573.735 arc seconds per century.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. I suspected that I missed something here. I was too much focused on the apsidal precession and forgot that the nodal precession affects the argument of the perihelion as well.

Comment: Apparently the cartesian coordinates are not affected by this nodal precession. Otherwise the arctan(y/x) calculation would not yield an approximately correct answer (transforming the coordinates into the orbital plane of the planet (so that the z-coordinate is zero) would make it exact I guess). One more question in this context: the 'period of revolution' PR in the elements: is it defined in a reference frame where the ellipse is at rest (e.g.time from perihelion passage to perihelion pasage)?

Comment: The $\arctan(y/x)$ approach yields a close to correct result because Mercury's orbit is only slightly inclined (by about 7°) w.r.t. the ecliptic, making $\arctan(y/x)$  yield something close to the longitude of perihelion. The correct way to calculate the longitude of perihelion is to add the right ascension of ascending node and the argument of perihelion. Longitude of perihelion is used because solar system astronomers prefer that measure due to the low inclination of many solar system objects. Also note that longitude of perihelion is a dogleg rather than an angle.

Comment: Whether that dogleg is physically meaningful is another question. But that's what is used, see for example [Precession of Mercury's Perihelion from Ranging to the MESSENGER Spacecraft](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/1538-3881/aa5be2).

Comment: Well, the Horizons data don't contain any information regarding any angles in the Cartesian vector mode. It is only x,y,z coordinates, and those are defined through the earth's ecliptic and equator, so there is no reference to the orbital plane of the planet at all. If I rotate the Horizon x,y,z coordinates around the x-axis by the inclination angle i of Mercury's orbit, I get via y'=y*cos(i)+z*sin(i) a corrected value of 572.64"/cy for the precession, so very close to the official.value (too close for any nodal precession to explain the remaining difference)

Comment: The orbital elements you requested are also defined in terms of the Earth's mean equator and ecliptic at J2000. Mercury's precession is defined in terms of that, or in terms of some other coordinate system based on the Earth. If you want to know the angular change between Mercury's perihelion position over time, the best thing to use would be the angular change in Mercury's eccentricity vector as expressed in a common inertial frame of reference. With the given data, that would result in a value of 578.593"/cy, but that is not how Mercury's precession is calculated.

Comment: Alternatively, you could have used the angular difference between the two position vectors you found, as both are very close to perihelion. That would have yielded a value of 577.309"/cy. But Mercury's precession is not defined in terms of the angular difference between perihelion positions. It's defined in terms of the change in the longitude of perihelion as measured from some Earth-based ecliptic reference frame.

Comment: One last comment: Assuming a Keplerian orbit, the Cartesian position and velocity coordinates of a planet along with the Sun's standard gravitational parameter are all one needs to calculate orbital elements. JPL's HORIZON system calculates orbital elements (osculating orbital elements, to be precise) using the assumption of a Keplerian orbit.